# i m getting the cursor in center. i want this cursor at the top in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I m using an image in edittext. image is quite big so the cursor come in middle

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titletobeset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:maxLines="200"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpape"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true">       
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:gravity="left|top"
```

in gravity you can set the position of text which is indeed the starting position of the cursor

Answer (score 1):

try to add following properties in your edit text

```
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```